# Sort Products based on the latest Order that referenced it - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I need to show a list of products sorted by the latest orders that had this product in its composition.
An image for reference:

[image]

And then you'd have `Product 2` with it's corresponding orders sorted by the order's creation date.
So, I'll have to group the orders based on the presence of a product, then order these groups based on the latest order within it.
This will be used to show the "most recent ordered products" but I have no idea on how to write the query without bloated super expensive methods.
Could someone provide any references please?

Comment: So you need to display all the dates for each product sorted in descending, or rather, just the most recent date for each product? Is the end result an output of 1 row per product or many rows per product?

Comment: Yes, just the most recent date for each product! The result will be 1 row per product

Comment: Please share table structure and some sample data for more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have two tables as below:
Products (productid, Name etc..)
Orders (orderid, order_date, product_id etc..)

Then you first need to sort the orders for a particular product by order_date. I have used CTE with row_number() function to achieve that then have selected only the first order information order by order_date in descending order.

```
with order_product as (
select o.orderid,o.order_date,o.product_id,p.name,row_number()over(partition by o.product_id order by order_date desc)rn
 from orders o inner join products p on o.productid=p.productid
) select * from order_product where rn=1
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you!