# What is the Query to sort the shop on base of latest order?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, query-builder

The store has a one-to-many relationship with order and I want to sort the shop with respect to the latest order so what will be the query to sort all store w.r.t latest order.                                   Thanks-Hashir Hamza

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: brother! I am new to laravel it is just a task that what is the query to show all shops (its a Model) on the sequence of latest order (like which shop placed an order recently  and show all shop on behalf of latest order)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107634/sort-products-based-on-the-latest-order-that-referenced-it-postgresql question is like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method latest() or you can use orderByDesc('created_at')

Sample:

```
$orders = Order::orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
```

OR

```
$orders = Order::latest()->get();
```

Comment: sorry if you don't get it * I don't want to show the latest order. want to show all shop(Model) which  placed orders(Model) in descending order

Comment: Okay can you attach a code snippet of what you have already?